# Calling this.props.dispatch twice

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I am using redux-form and I want to call dispatch 2 times for a single form change, However, using the code below, only the first `this.props.dispatch` gets dispatched. I.e, `startDate` gets updated but `endDate` doesn't and results in an error. Is there a way to dispatch both?

```
 handleEvent(event, picker) {


        let changeStartDate = change('FilterForm', 'startDate', picker.startDate);
        let changeEndDate = change('FilterForm', 'endDate', picker.endDate);

        this.props.dispatch(changeStartDate);
        this.props.dispatch(changeEndDate);
}
```

**EDIT:**
When I pass the two actions as `this.props.dispatch(changeStartDate, changeEndDate),` only the first parameter, `startDate` gets updated in the redux-form. Same behavior as calling on separate lines. When I put `changeEndDate` as the first parameter, the `changeEndDate gets changed too. So, whichever comes first, gets updated in redux-form.

Comment: Why u can not passed both `changeStartDate` & `changeEndDate ` in single dispatch?  are these function or plain data?

Comment: You need to pass the parameter as a single one like
this.props.dispatch(changeStartDate, changeEndDate);

Comment: @PrakashP when I pass them like that only the first parameter, `startDate` gets updated in the redux-form. Same behavior as calling on separate lines. When I put endDate as the first parameter, the endDate gets changes too. So, whichever comes first, gets updated in redux-form.

Comment: @Pila Can you please share the source code of your reducer and corresponding action ? It ll be more helpful